# How to find out what the modules do for python

Tags: python, function, module

Ok, I know the dir() function , but I get all this

```
>>> dir(sys)
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', '_debugmallocstats', '_getframe', '_home', '_mercurial', '_xoptions', 'api_version', 'argv', 'base_exec_prefix', 'base_prefix', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dllhandle', 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_info', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'getswitchinterval', 'gettrace', 'getwindowsversion', 'hash_info', 'hexversion', 'implementation', 'int_info', 'intern', 'last_traceback', 'last_type', 'last_value', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'setcheckinterval', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit', 'setswitchinterval', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'thread_info', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions', 'winver']
```

I don't know what any of these do. I heard of the help() function, but it doesn't  work for me or when I add ' ' it doesn't give me any info

```
>>> help(path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    help(path)
NameError: name 'path' is not defined

>>> help('path')
no Python documentation found for 'path'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `help` exactly the same way you call `dir`. Therefore:

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys)

Help on built-in module sys:

NAME
    sys

FILE
    (built-in)

MODULE DOCS
    http://docs.python.org/library/sys

DESCRIPTION
    This module provides access to some objects used or maintained by the
    interpreter and to functions that interact strongly with the interpreter.
... (lot of text follows)
```

Since there is no module nor symbol path `help(path)` can't find anything. And adding quotes won't help anything. However:

```
>>> help(sys.path)

Help on list object:

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
... (lot of text follows)
```

But note, that it prints help on the class of the passed object, `list`, NOT on the variable. Variables are not first-class objects in python so the command can't find out that the argument comes from `sys.path` and the help for it can only be found in the module. Functions have the help attached to the function objects, so `help` does print help for specific functions you pass.

Comment: Ahh perfect, the second code was exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the built-in documentation available via `help()`, don't forget about the [excellent online documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/). You can look through the [module index](http://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html) (Python 2 link), or just google something like [`python sys.path`](https://www.google.com/#q=python+sys.path) and usually the first link will take you right to it. Once you're there, you can select the exact version you're using via the dropdown menu in the upper left corner.